# Reset multiselect drop-down menu react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, function

I'm using multiselect-dropdown-react in my form, my question is, how do I reset the multiselect field, I mean the input with the options? because I have really seen the documentation and I can't find a way to reset, the entire form is reset, except the multiselect.

```
const multiselectRef = useRef();

    function resetValues() {
   multiselectRef.resetSelectedValues();
  }

  <Multiselect
    options={props.categories}
    displayValue="name"
    onSelect={handlerOnChangeCategory}
    onRemove={handlerOnChangeCategory}
    ref={resetValues}
   />
```

Thank you, I appreciate

Comment: Which library are you using?

Comment: I'm using https://www.npmjs.com/package/multiselect-react-dropdown

Comment: I still dont understand the question. Do you want to reset form when someone click something?

Comment: The form resets with a simple onSubmit, but the multiselect does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correct you want to reset the multiselect on some action. You can do this simply like this:

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import { Multiselect } from "multiselect-react-dropdown";

import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [options] = useState([
    { name: "Srigar", id: 1 },
    { name: "Sam", id: 2 }
  ]);
  const multiselectRef = useRef();

  const resetSelectField = () => {
    multiselectRef.current.resetSelectedValues();
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <Multiselect
        options={options} // Options to display in the dropdown
        displayValue="name" // Property name to display in the dropdown options
        ref={multiselectRef}
      />
      <button onClick={resetSelectField}>Reset</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-sound-3ek6n?file=/src/App.js:0-786

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll try that and let you know

Comment: Cool. If this works for you make sure upvote this and mark accepted answer. If any one stuck on same problem then this question will pop up(stackoverflow algorithm)